# delaying the loading of a certain css background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading, background-image

in a CSS like this :

```
...
#big-menu {
    background: #fff url(../images/big-menu.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#some-menu {
    background: #fff url(../images/some-menu.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#some-other-menu {
    background: #fff url(../images/some-other-menu.jpg) no-repeat;
}
...
```

is there a way to delay the loading of `#big-menu`'s background image, so that it loads after everything else, including all of the images in the HTML, and every other CSS background (the `some-menu` and `some-other-menu`).

The reason is, big-menu.jpg is very heavy in size, and I want it to be loaded last. After all, it just serves as an eye-candy, and there are other background images that have a better use than that. (such as the ones used in buttons)

Does the order of putting it in CSS or the occurrences of the markup (`#big-menu`) in HTML got anything to do with what gets loaded first ? or is there a more reliable way to control it ? javascript (jQuery preferred) is fine.

Comment: Hi andy                        !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ordering in css doesn't control which resources are loaded first, but do affect what existing style is being overwritten or inherited.

Try the JavaScript onload event. The event executes only after the page is finish loading.

```
function loadBG(){
    document.getElementById("big-menu").style.backgroundImage="url(../images/big-menu.jpg)";
}
window.onload=loadBG();
```

Comment: would all the images and all other background images finished loading when this function called ? the onload event, AFAIK, is triggered when the HTML, not the images, finished loading.

Comment: The onload event is triggered when all resources on the page have finished loding, including images and iframes and css files and javascript files.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `window.onload=loadBG;` (no parentheses)? My IDE complains about the parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be a perfect solution(as it is a css-background and not a image), but [YUI Image loader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/imageloader/) provides a good way of lazy-loading images.

Create a group

```
var imgGroup = new YAHOO.util.ImageLoader.group(window, 'load', 2);
```

After the document has loaded, the image will load 2 seconds after it. See [Yahoo! Shine](http://shine.yahoo.com/) or the [examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/imageloader/index.html) for demo.

Comment: Also see this link for a jQuery equivalent: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to split your assets over different domains, browsers will only request two assets at time then wait for one to be loaded before starting the next. You can observe this with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) and [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), so placing some assets on images.example.com and images1.example.com and see if that makes an impact

Comment: good answer. I've thought about that, but it seemed rather cumbersome and is not exactly feasible right now, given that I only need to delay that one image and I do not have the access to subdomains. Nevertheless, +1 :)

Comment: Worth noting for 2013 that most modern browsers load much more assets at a time concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think placement in the styelsheet will affect it, as the order of the elements to which they are applied will decide which image will be loaded first.

You could use jQuery to load the images in the right sequence, though

```
$('firstElement').addClass('some-menu');
$('secondElement').addClass('some-other-menu');
$('lastElement').addClass('big-menu');
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, so then maybe instead of adding a class, a better solution would be to add the background-images in runtime.

```
$('firstElement').css("background-image", "some-menu.jpg");
$('secondElement').css("background-image", "some-other-menu.jpg");
$('lastElement').css("background-image", "big-menu.jpg");
```

Comment: Images that are referenced in a style sheet will come across the wire even if they are not used in the actual layout. Adding a class will simply delay when they are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling when an image loads in CSS is not really possible. You could try putting it at the very bottom of your StyleSheet but I doubt you'll see an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The order of downloading can't be controlled by using css. However you can use javascript to achieve this.

Although not directly related to the question maybe before doing that you should optmize the image by using smush.it or your favorite image program I find that jpegs look very good when saved at 85% quality. Experiment and don't forget to set your web server to cache images for long periods and then the problem will just be the first time your users go to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's Javascript trick worked for me in solving this problem. However, I had to correct the syntax slightly:

```
function loadBG(){
     document.getElementById("big-menu").style.backgroundImage="url(../images/big-menu.jpg)";
}
window.onload=loadBG();
```